# Last.fm Scrobbler connection error

Tags: internet, last.fm-client

I get a connection error during the set up of the scrobbler.

I enter my username and password, press next, then a "Connection Error" window pops up. It is telling me that it could not connect to the internet, even though I have a fine Ethernet connection.

It is asking me if I use a proxy to connect to the internet, and asks for my proxy details.

I enter the information, but the same window pops up again:

[image: The message i get]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Open Rhythmbox and click on the Last.fm library;

[image: Step_1]

2. Start a session on Last.fm and give permission to Rhythmbox;

[image: Step_2.1]
[image: Step_2.2]
[image: Step_2.3]

3. Play a song and check if Last.fm will scrobble.